# Radio Button auto deselect after selection

Tags: android

I have four radio buttons in a radio group in my MCQ app. When I select a radio button and go to next question, there is a problem if I select same radio button as previous, the radio button automatically deselect, but after selecting any other button, it is working.

```
private int getSelectedAnswer(int radioSelected){
    int answerSelected = 0;
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio0){
        answerSelected = 1;
    }
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio1){
        answerSelected = 2;
    }
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio2){
        answerSelected = 3;
    }
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio3){
        answerSelected = 4;
    }
    return answerSelected;
}
private void selectedRadioButton(int ansSelected){
    if(ansSelected == 1){
        optionOne.setChecked(true);
    }
    if(ansSelected == 2){
        optionTwo.setChecked(true);
    }
    if(ansSelected == 3){
        optionThree.setChecked(true);
    }
    if(ansSelected == 4){
        optionFour.setChecked(true);
    }
}
private void uncheckedRadioButton(){
    optionOne.setChecked(false);
    optionTwo.setChecked(false);
    optionThree.setChecked(false);
    optionFour.setChecked(false);
}
private void showQuestions(){
    if(currentQuizQuestion >= quizCount){
        currentQuizQuestion=currentQuizQuestion-1;
        Toast.makeText(ShowSingleQuestionsOnline.this, "End of the Quiz Questions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    else {
        uncheckedRadioButton();
          quizQuestion.setText(1+ currentQuizQuestion + " : " + MyQuestArrList.get(currentQuizQuestion).get("QuestName"));

        int dd=Integer.parseInt(MyQuestArrList.get(currentQuizQuestion).get("QueType"),10);
            optionOne.setText(MyQuestArrList.get(currentQuizQuestion).get("QueOption1"));
            optionTwo.setText(MyQuestArrList.get(currentQuizQuestion).get("QueOption2"));
            optionThree.setText(MyQuestArrList.get(currentQuizQuestion).get("QueOption3"));
            optionFour.setText(MyQuestArrList.get(currentQuizQuestion).get("QueOption4"));
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal because the radio option state is not reset.

Take a look on your getSelectedAnswer() method :

```
private int getSelectedAnswer(int radioSelected){
    int answerSelected = 0;
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio0){
        answerSelected = 1;
    }
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio1){
        answerSelected = 2;
    }
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio2){
        answerSelected = 3;
    }
    if(radioSelected == R.id.radio3){
        answerSelected = 4;
    }
    return answerSelected;
}
```

When you go to the next question, the selected radio option state remain and when you click again on it, it value change (deselect).

To avoid this, you need to reset your radio options before go to the next question.

Comment: uncheckedRadioButton();
this function reset all radioButtons before go to next question.